# Updating Sub folder and File renaming batch script

Tags: batch-file

Need a bit of help with this script

```
for /d %%D in ("*") do (
  for %%F in ("%%D\*.jpg") do (
    ren "%%~dpF(*).txt" "(*) %%~nF.*"
  )
)
```

This is the original script and this is what it does

```
Before
filename.jpg
(1).txt

Result
filename.jpg
(1) filename.txt
```

it copies the filename from the jpg and adds it to the filename of the txt file

what I have been trying to do is two things 
I want to add a controlled Sub folder reader to it, and I would like to the filename to be copied between certain points of the txt files

```
Before
filename.jpg
(1)(name).txt

Result
filename.jpg
(1) filename (name).txt
```

I have tried like 10 different ways to make this work and for some reason I can't

tried this

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "Ready\(*)(Name).txt"') DO call :label "%%q"
goto :eof

:Label
set "FILE=%~1"
for /d %%D in ("*") do (
  for %%F in ("%%D\*.jpg") do (
    ren "%%~dpF(*)(Name).txt" "(*) %%~nF (*).*"
  )
)
```

and I removed this as well `for /d %%D in ("*") do (` 
and tried this

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "Ready\(*)(Name).txt"') DO call :label "%%q"
goto :eof

:Label
set "FILE=%~1"
  for %%F in ("*.jpg") do (
    ren "%%~dpF%~1" "(*) %%~nF (*).*"
)
```

and tried this

```
for /d %%D in ('dir /b /s /a-d "*"') do (
  for %%F in ("%%D\*.jpg") do (
    ren "%%~dpF(*)(Name).txt" "(*) %%~nF (*).*"
  )
)
```

Any help would be great

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the source directory is a name which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

for /d %%B in ("*") do (
 for %%E in ("%%B\*.jpg") do (
  FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=()" %%q IN ('dir /b /a-d "%%~dpnxB\(*)(*).txt" 2^>nul') DO (
   rem files matching "(*)(*).txt only
    REN "%%~dpnxB\(%%q)(%%r).txt" "(%%q) %%~nE (%%r).txt"
  )
  FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=()" %%q IN ('dir /b /a-d "%%~dpnxB\(*).txt" 2^>nul') DO IF /i "%%r" equ ".txt" (
   rem files matching "(*).txt only
    REN "%%~dpnxB\(%%q).txt" "(%%q) %%~nE.txt"
  )
 )
)

popd

GOTO :EOF
```

Caution : This batch is armed. It will rename files. Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

The outer loop on `%%B` gets the directory names. No surprise there.

The next loop on `%%E` gets the `.jpg` names. No surprise there.

The first loop on `%%q` looks at the `.txt` files that fit the pattern `(*)(*).txt` and re-assembles the parts as required for the rename.

The second loop on `%%q` looks at the `.txt` files that fit the pattern `(*).txt` which may include the just-renamed files matching `(*)(*).txt` now `(*) jpgfilename (*).txt`, so this time, `%%r` must be `.txt` to exclude these newly-renamed files.

I'll repeat
Caution : This batch is armed. It will rename files. Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Comment: wow that is a lot, I was way off...lol Thank you very much I will test and I am always careful that is why I like to add folder names to control where it scans `SET "sourcedir=%~dp0Original"`

Comment: Hey I can't seem to get it working, where you able to make it work. also I added `/s` since I needed a sub reader, but before this I still couldn't make it work

Comment: Yes - this was a copy/paste of my working code. To have it scan subdirectories, change `for /d` to `for /d /r`. Sadly "it doesn't work" leads to a guessing game. Try targeting a small test directory tree as `sourcedir` and change the `ren` commands to `echo ren` (to simply report the expected rename) and add a line `echo directory "%%B"` directly after the `for /d /r` line, and add another line `echo found "%%E"` directly after the `for %%E` line, This should show you which directories are detected and which `.jpg`s are found. Copy/paste the code - don't retype! And no `/s` in the `dir`s

Comment: Thank you the `/r` fixed it, I did try placing the files directly under the source folder without any subfolders to read and it did fail, so I figured the the `/s` missing was the issue, now with `/r` the script is working Thank you